# With AgGrid React, Is there a way to preserve column widths across React rerenders?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm seeing unexpected column width changes when rerendering a React component that contains an AgGrid.

Repro:

1. Render an AgGrid with React
2. Drag a column to change its width
3. Rerender the AgGrid with new data

Expected:

- Column retains its width

Actual:

- Column snaps back to its original width.

Is there a way to get columns to retain their width, kind of like [suppressScrollOnNewData](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-scrolling-suppressScrollOnNewData), but for maintaining column width?